# ¿Como crear un instalador desatendido de MySQL Server con contraseña de root?

Tags: mysql, cmd, zip

INSTALACIÓN DE MYSQL SERVER DESDE ZIP Y LINEA DE COMANDOS PARA CREAR UN INSTALADOR DESATENDIDO.

PREREQUISITOS:
El Archivo my.ini, debe de estar dentro de C:\mysql
Y dicho archivo debe contener lo siguiente:
[mysqld]

## directorio de instalacion

basedir= "C:\mysql\"

## diretorio de datos

datadir= "C:\mysql\data"
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

## secure-file-priv = ""

Y debe existirla carpeta data para que allí se guarden nuestras configuraciones

INSTALACIÓN

Paso 1: instalar las librerías de 32 y 64 bits de Visual C++ studio 2013 Redistributable.
Paso 2: Copiar la carpeta de mySQL, ya preparada con su archivo my.ini a C:
Paso 3: Renombrar dicha carpeta a “mySQL”
Paso 4: Abrir una ventana de comandos “COMO ADMINISTRADOR” y ubicarnos en C:/MySQL/bin
Paso 5: Inicializar mysql como modo “Inseguro”:    mysqld --initialize-insecure
Paso 6: Instalar el Servicio de mysql:  mysqld --install   (debe decir: Service Succesfully installed)
Paso 7: Luego iniciar el servicio:
NET START MySQL
(Si todo sale bien, debe salir: El Servicio de MySQL está iniciando, luego El servicio de MySQL se ha iniciado correctamente)
Paso 8: Establecemos la contraseña de Root así:
mysql -uroot -e"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION"
Paso 9: Detenemos el servicio mySQL:
NET STOP MySQL
Paso 10: Luego volvemos a iniciar el servicio, esta vez de modo seguro:
NET START MySQL

LISTO:
PARA PROBAR PODEMOS HACER LO SIGUIENTE:
1.- Volver a ejecutar mysql -u root, y veremos que ya no nos va a dejar sin contraseña
2.- Ejecutar mysql -u root -p, a continuación nos pide la contraseña, si todo salió bien, detectará la contraseña y nos dará acceso.

setx PATH "C:\mysql\bin" /M.    (AÑADE EN VARIABLES DE SISTEMA)
setx PATH "C:\mysql\bin”.   (AÑADE EN VARIABLES DE USUARIO)

hecho esto ya tendremos mysql server instalado, ahora el problema es que me borra el Path de las variables de entorno de sistema de los demás programas, alguna sugerencia??

Comment: Ya lo logré, esto fue lo que hice, voy a aportar, dado que parece que todos los tutorales están desfasados y tuve que agarrar pedazos de todos lados.